# How to extract content of each superpixel and resize them?

Tags: python, superpixels

[SuperPixeled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPgbX.png)

This is the image and I want to save only the non-black region superpixels after resizing them to 56x56. I am working on superpixel classification.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What is the problem you encounter?

Comment: i am using slic of skimage.segmentation to create the segments these return numpy array  so I am getting stuck here how to save these segments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skimage.measure.regionprops`.

```
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.measure import regionprops

# Assume image is given
segments = slic(image, n_segments=numSegments, compactness=0.1,enforce_connectivity=True)
props = regionprops(segments,intensity_image=image)

segmentsToExclude = []
for s, segment in enumerate(segments):
    if props[s].mean_intensity < 5: # basically black
        segmentsToExclude.append(s)
```

Something along those lines.  Check out [this skimage link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) for more information on regionprops.